# Possible conflict between dcolumn and csvsimple

Tags: csv, csvsimple, dcolumn

Ok, so I'm trying to add a table to a document using a .csv file.

After tinkering with it I've got this for the table:

```
\usepackage{makeidx}  % allows for indexgeneration
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage[toc]{glossaries}

\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
     \csvreader[no head,
        tabular=c | d{2}  l | d{2} | l,
        table head = Nivel & \mathrm{Tokens} & (Max) & \mathrm{Tempo} & Sucesso \\\hline,
        late after line= \\,
        late after last line=\\\hline]{BC14.csv}{}
    {\csvcoli & \csvcolii & \csvcoliii & \csvcoliv & \csvcolv}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

the .csv file contains this:

```
01,1.35,(2),12.2,0.65
02,1.7,(3),45,0
03,1.2,(3),58.2,0.05
04,2.63158,(4),76.47369,0.10526
05,1,(2),70,0
06,1.2,(2),30.5,0.35
07,1,(3),60,0
08,2.10526,(3),38.78947,0.26316
09,2.05263,(3),77.1579,0.10526
10,0.52941,(3),100,0
```

the output looks like this:
[image: table]

I've looked everywhere but I can't find any instance of dcolumn failing to round the numbers, but I also didn't find any examples using both dcolumn and csvsimple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, there is no conflict between `dcolumn` and `csvsimple`. If `csvsimple` is removed and the table is typeset directly by filling in the data manually, the output is identical.

The `dcolumn` package is intended for columns which are to be aligned on a decimal point, but `dcolumn` does not round numbers.

To round numbers automatically, there are other packages. `siunitx` for example allows rounding of numbers (and many other things).

To typeset the columns *Tokens* and *Tempo* with two digits after the decimal point, the following code can be used:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
     \csvreader[no head,
        before reading=\sisetup{round-mode=places,round-precision=2,round-integer-to-decimal},
        tabular={c | S l | S | l},
        table head = Nivel & {Tokens} & (Max) & {Tempo} & Sucesso \\\hline,
        late after line= \\,
        late after last line=\\\hline]{BC14.csv}{}
    {\csvcoli & \csvcolii & \csvcoliii & \csvcoliv & \csvcolv}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I guess rounding was a poor way to put it, but it was supposed to limit the number of decimal places (which I guess was good enough). Anyways, thanks for the answer, I had already read about `siunitx` but had no idea how to apply it in these circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

There is no conflict between the `dcolumn` and `csvsimple` packages. It's just that some of the information in the table header was set up incorrectly.

Assuming you want to stick with the `dcolumn` package, you should do the following two things:

- Replace the instruction

  ```
  tabular=c | d{2}  l | d{2} | l,
  ```

  with

  ```
  tabular=c | d{1.5} l | d{3.5} | l,
  ```

  Basically, the `d{2}` specification is faulty since it reserves only 2 digits worth of space for the integer components of the numbers, and *no space at all* for the decimal component.
- Replace the line

  ```
  table head = Nivel & \mathrm{Tokens} & (Max) & \mathrm{Tempo} & Sucesso \\\hline,
  ```

  with

  ```
  table head = Nivel & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Tokens} & (Max) & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Tempo} & Sucesso \\\hline,
  ```

With these two mofications in place, your table will typeset just fine.